# IIS6 MVC2 Server starts sending out 404 after a while

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6, http-status-code-404, application-pool

I have a W2k3 server running IIS6 and MVC2 (.net 4).

Right after the iis starts, everything works ok, the site runs fine. Extensionless urls work ok.

After a certain period of time (maybe of inactivity) the server stops working and starts to send 404 errors to the client.

As soon as I restart de application pool, everithing goes back to normal and the site is up again. The thing is, I shouldn't be restarting the application pool every few hours.

Any thoughts?

Comment: might need to ask this on serverfault - sounds to me like an IIS issue, but I could be wrong.

Comment: maybe, I wasn't sure where to ask

Comment: Is it just extensionless pages that get 404? Just .NET pages? All content?

Comment: For the whole content. The same happens no matter if it is a route to a controller, an .aspx page or any static other static file on the site.

Comment: If it's the whole content, then I don't think the programming is the problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by deleting the websites and application pools from iis and creating them back.